# I am trying to scan through some excel files and copy data but the data is not being copied to a new sheet cant work out why

Tags: excel, openpyxl

I have written a programme that reads through a folder containing excel sheets and is supposed to copy the data it finds for specific x and y headings in the sheets. I have been through the sheets and made sure that the information is there but the sheet it is supposed to copy it to remains blank, can anyone explain why it might be?  I have written some debugging code to try and show if it was reading the sheets correctly and it appears to be doing so. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

This is the code I have written:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook
import os
from datetime import datetime
from tqdm import tqdm

# Set up paths to input and output files
scan_folder_path = os.path.expanduser("c:\\Users\\n.margot\\Desktop\\scan")
output_file_path = os.path.expanduser("c:\\Users\\n.margot\\Desktop\\m2m.xlsx")

# Set up dictionary of headings
headings = {
    "Brent Swaps": [datetime(2023, 6, 1), datetime(2023, 7, 1), datetime(2023, 8, 1), datetime(2023, 9, 1), datetime(2023, 10, 1), datetime(2023, 11, 1), datetime(2023, 12, 1)],
    "EBOB": [datetime(2023, 4, 1), datetime(2023, 7, 1), datetime(2023, 8, 1), datetime(2023, 9, 1)],
    "Crack": [datetime(2023, 7, 1), datetime(2023, 8, 1), datetime(2023, 9, 1), datetime(2024, 1, 1)],
    "F/P": [datetime(2023, 7, 1), datetime(2023, 8, 1), datetime(2023, 9, 1)],
}

# Format dates to only include year and month
for key in headings:
    headings[key] = [date.strftime("%Y-%m") for date in headings[key]]

# Load the output workbook
if os.path.exists(output_file_path):
    output_wb = load_workbook(output_file_path)
else:
    output_wb = Workbook()

# Set the active sheet in the output workbook
output_sheet = output_wb.active

# Loop over files in scan folder
for file_name in tqdm(os.listdir(scan_folder_path), desc="Processing Files"):
    if file_name.endswith(".xlsx"):
        # Load the input workbook
        input_wb = load_workbook(os.path.join(scan_folder_path, file_name))

        # Loop over sheets in the input workbook
        for sheet_name in input_wb.sheetnames:
            print(f"Processing sheet {sheet_name} in file {file_name}")
            input_sheet = input_wb[sheet_name]
            # Loop over headings and copy data to output sheet
            for x_heading, y_headings in headings.items():
                x_col = None
                y_cols = []
                for col in range(1, input_sheet.max_column + 1):
                    cell = input_sheet.cell(row=1, column=col)
                    if cell.value == x_heading:
                        x_col = col
                    elif cell.value:
                        try:
                            date_val = datetime.strptime(str(cell.value), '%d/%m/%Y').date()
                            if date_val.replace(day=1) in y_headings:
                                y_cols.append(col)
                        except ValueError:
                            pass

                # If the x and y headings were found, copy the data to the output sheet
                if x_col is not None and y_cols:
                    print(f"Copying data from {sheet_name} ({x_heading})...")
                    for row in range(2, input_sheet.max_row + 1):
                        x_value = input_sheet.cell(row=row, column=x_col).value
                        if x_value is not None:
                            output_sheet.cell(row=len(output_sheet['A']) + 1, column=1).value = sheet_name
                            output_sheet.cell(row=len(output_sheet['A']), column=2).value = x_heading
                            output_sheet.cell(row=len(output_sheet['A']),column=3).value = x_value
                            for y_col in y_cols:
                                y_value = input_sheet.cell(row=row, column=y_col).value
                                if y_value is not None:
                                 y_heading = input_sheet.cell(row=1, column=y_col).value
                                 output_sheet.cell(row=len(output_sheet['A']), column=4).value = y_heading
                                 output_sheet.cell(row=len(output_sheet['A']), column=5).value = y_value



# Save the output workbook
output_wb.save(output_file_path)
print(f"Data has been copied to {output_file_path}")
```

This is the debugging:

```
C:\Users\n.margot\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\n.margot\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py 
Processing Files:   0%|          | 0/4 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Processing sheet Sheet1 in file Curves 240323.xlsx
Processing sheet Sheet2 in file Curves 240323.xlsx
Processing sheet Sheet3 in file Curves 240323.xlsx
Processing sheet Sheet4 in file Curves 240323.xlsx
Processing sheet Sheet5 in file Curves 240323.xlsx
Processing sheet Sheet6 in file Curves 240323.xlsx
Processing sheet Market in file The COB-Advanced 20230324.xlsx
Processing sheet Rollover in file The COB-Advanced 20230324.xlsx
Processing Files: 100%|██████████| 4/4 [00:00<00:00, 26.74it/s]
Data has been copied to c:\Users\n.margot\Desktop\m2m.xlsx

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I think your try/except should be set to output on the exception. Openpyxl reads date dates as datetime.

Comment: I think that would give me a lot of error messages. I am trying to keep it clean and just copy the data across.

Comment: Well what I mean is that every 'try' results in an exception, y_cols has no values so nothing happens.